# How to remove icons from KDE application dropdown menu items?

Tags: unity, gnome, icons, kde, menu

What is the configuration setting to **not** show icons next to menu dropdown items for KDE applications installed in Ubuntu?

Gnome applications do *not* display an icon next to dropdown menu items.  However, KDE applications installed in Ubuntu *do* display an icon next to dropdown menu items.

Here is an example of a KDE application.  Notice the icons next to the menu items.

[image: KDE Menu Dropdown with Icons]

Here is an example of a Gnome application.  Notice there are no icons next to the menu items.

[image]

Is there an appropriate entry in /usr/share/kde4/config/kdeglobals (or other configuration file) to achieve this result?

I have unsuccessfully tried the following entries in kdeglobals.

```
[KDE]
ShowIconsInMenuItems=false
ShowIconsOnPushButtons=false
```

If you can't identify the correct configuration file and entry, steps using KDE System Settings (installed via the systemsettings package) will also suffice.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option for that in KDE's `systemsettings`, in

```
Application Appearence > Style > Fine Tuning
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  Under "Fine Tuning" I found "Show Icons on buttons" and "Show Icons in menus".  Both were unchecked (false), as configured in kdeglobals.  I changed "Main toolbar text" to "Text Only" but this only removed icons from the in-window toolbar-- not what I wanted.  Changing "Secondary toolbar text" to "Text Only" had no effect.  Trying different options for "Menubar style" had no effect.  With all of these options, icons still appeared in the Unity global menu-bar drop-downs.  (Also these changes had no effect on Unity's Locally Integrated Menus, either).

Comment: Looks like the only action left is to file a bug report against `unity` or whatever package is responsible for menus.